# Puffing Billy and Multiple Capybara Session

Tags: web-scraping, rspec, capybara

I am trying to use RSpec to test a library that uses Capybara to read data from websites.

I want to use PuffingBilly to record the interactions within this library, but I cannot get PuffingBilly to respond at all, because I think it is focused on the instance of Capybara that RSpec is using.

How do I get PuffingBilly to interdict requests from this other Capybara::Session?

Backtrace

6: from /home/jessethebuilder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/puffing-billy-2.1.1/lib/billy/proxy.rb:19:in block in start'
5: from /home/jessethebuilder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/puffing-billy-2.1.1/lib/billy/proxy.rb:70:inmain_loop' 4: from /home/jessethebuilder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:195:in run'
3: from /home/jessethebuilder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:195:inrun_machine' 2: from /home/jessethebuilder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/puffing-billy-2.1.1/lib/billy/proxy.rb:76:in block in main_loop'
1: from /home/jessethebuilder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:531:instart_server' /home/jessethebuilder/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:531:in `start_tcp_server': no acceptor (port is in use or requires root privileges) (RuntimeError)

Config (spec/spec_helper.rb)

```
Billy.configure do |c|
  c.cache = true
  c.cache_request_headers = false
  c.ignore_params = []
  c.path_blacklist = []
  c.merge_cached_responses_whitelist = []
  c.persist_cache = true
  c.ignore_cache_port = true # defaults to true
  c.non_successful_cache_disabled = false
  c.non_successful_error_level = :warn
  c.non_whitelisted_requests_disabled = false
  c.cache_path = 'spec/fixtures/billy/req_cache/'
  c.certs_path = 'spec/fixtures/billy/req_certs/'
  c.proxy_host = 'localhost'
  c.proxy_port = 4461
  # c.proxied_request_host = 'localhost'
  # c.proxied_request_port = 4461
  c.record_requests = true
  c.cache_request_body_methods = ['post', 'patch', 'put', 'get']
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to have puffing billy interact with the Capybara session within the library you'd need to configure the driver you're using for that session with the puffing billy proxy options

See https://github.com/oesmith/puffing-billy#customising-the-javascript-driver

Comment: I should not have down-voted this. If you edit it, I will rectify that.

Comment: I believe I am finding the proper port with Puffing-Billy,  but I am now getting this error: 'no acceptor (port is in use or requires root privileges)'

I have been able to find out very little info on this error.

Comment: @JesseFarmer If you add the code you're using to configure the session, and the full error (with stacktrace) to your question I may be able to provide more help - without that info it's tough to know exactly what is going on.

Comment: @JesseFarmer Please add info to your original question, not to answers (I've copied and pasted the info you provided to the question).  The configuration that matters is the configuration of the Capybara session in your app - not the PuffingBilly configuration directly - ie. you need to add the proxy info from PuffingBilly to the Capybara session not the other way around (which is what I think you've done).  Please add the code showing how you're configuring the Capybara session in the library to the original question.